# Part of header gets cut off only in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

There seems to be some type of bug in IE9

```
.WarningTableHeaderRow
{
    /*height: 18px;
    color: choose('Color', @blue, @green);*/    
    background-color: #FFD739;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-top: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding-left: 33px;
    /*margin-top: 15px;*/
    /*padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0.83em;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}
```

This code renders perfectly fine in all other browsers. It even renders perfectly fine in Internet Explorer 10 and above. I'm not sure why it happens. I tried changing just about everything there is to change about this CSS. Originally margin-top: 15px was used. I tried boredering or changing padding. Nothing works. And this error ONLY happens in IE9. Any advices?

Comment: can you post a example like fiddle link?

Comment: No, this is as much as I can post here :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that this CSS code was under `<tr>` tag which IE9 ignores for some reason. Just move these attributes to `<table>` and it works great